# How to find FULL DUPLICATES rows ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

how to find full duplicate strings? Not single values, strings.
Oracle...

```
SELECT 1col, 2col, 3col, COUNT(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY 1col, 2col, 3col
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But this solution is primitive and not elegant

Comment: That's the way it's done.

Comment: if there are a lot of columns?

Comment: Or. a [mcve] would make your question much clearer.

Comment: What do you mean by "Not single values, strings"? SQL table has only single value per each column per row as long as it is 1NF relation.

Comment: "Primitive" and "elegant" are subjectives which have no relationship to the result of executable code. Please clarify the real problem you want to solve.

Comment: If you don't know a better solution, how do you know yours is not elegant?

Comment: No, it's not primitive or inelegant.. it's the way it's done. None of the answers below is an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative which might run faster would be to use string concatenation:

```sql
SELECT 1col || 2col || 3col AS string
FROM tab
GROUP BY 1col || 2col || 3col
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Note that `'AB' || 'C'` = `'A' || 'BC'`. Same values?

Comment: Yes, can be prevented by adding a separator within the concatenation.

Comment: @jarlh I know...I thought that was the point of the problem, that the OP is viewing all 3 columns as a single string.  If not, then my answer is not valid and the current approach is probably the best.

Comment: This doesn't improve on elegance. And it worsens performance, as string concatenation takes CPU cycles that are unnecessary here. And what happens if the total length of the columns exceeds 4000 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3  -- all the columns
  ORDER BY col3                  -- can be anything as PARTITION BY contains all the
                                 -- columns
  PATTERN (^ any_row{2} )        -- look for the first 2 rows in the partition
  DEFINE
    any_row AS 1 = 1             -- does not matter as the PARTITION BY clause is
                                 -- separating the rows into unique groups
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( col1, col2, col3 ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 4 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2y7g9op4)

Comment: An uncommon and fresh way to do this task. Did you perform performance testing of this solution compared to classic `having count(*) > 1`? It would be interesting to see because I didn't test `match recognize` internals a lot.

Comment: Don't you think this is harder to understand, more complicated and less elegant overall than what the questioner started with? I also suspect this performs poorly, but only testing would confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You can find duplicate rows using analytic function or an inline view.

```
CREATE TABLE fruits (
        fruit_id   NUMBER generated BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
        fruit_name VARCHAR2(100),
        color VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO fruits(fruit_name,color) VALUES('Apple','Red');
INSERT INTO fruits(fruit_name,color) VALUES('Apple','Red');
INSERT INTO fruits(fruit_name,color) VALUES('Orange','Orange');
INSERT INTO fruits(fruit_name,color) VALUES('Orange','Orange');
INSERT INTO fruits(fruit_name,color) VALUES('Orange','Orange');
INSERT INTO fruits(fruit_name,color) VALUES('Banana','Yellow');
INSERT INTO fruits(fruit_name,color) VALUES('Banana','Green');

/* analytic function */

WITH fruit_counts AS (
    SELECT f.*,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY fruit_name, color) c
    FROM fruits f
)
SELECT *
FROM fruit_counts
WHERE c > 1 ;

/* inline view */

SELECT 
    *
FROM
        (SELECT f.*,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY fruit_name, color) c
        FROM fruits f
        )
WHERE c > 1;

FRUIT_ID    FRUIT_NAME  COLOR   C
2   Apple   Red 2
1   Apple   Red 2
5   Orange  Orange  3
3   Orange  Orange  3
4   Orange  Orange  3
```